How to migrate a jiva volume replica from a cluster node to another?
I have a 4 nodes Kubernetes test cluster where we have installed openebs jiva as storage solution.
I'm currently using a replica 3 configuration and I need to find a way to move one of the replicas from one node to another.
This is necessary since we might need to run maintenance on the cluster and cordon + drain a node.
In this case the jiva replica is evicted from the node but not automatically rescheduled on another one (and since we have 4 nodes and 3 replicas, due to anti affinity rules already in place by default it should be rescheduled on the only node without any jiva replicas).
How can I achieve that?
Thanks in advance
